# Posting form data using .save() to pass url parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The page i am posting accepts parameter like id,email

how do i send

```
/index?id=001&email=user@email.com
```

in backbone.js

```
model.save()?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a `sync` method into your model definition.

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function(method, model, options){
        return $.ajax({
            type:         'POST',
            contentType:  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            beforeSend:   function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'POST');
            },
            dataType:     'json',
            url:          '/index?id=' + this.get('id') + '&email=' + this.get('email')
        });
    }
});


myModel = new MyModel({
    'id': '001',
    'email': 'user@email.com'
});

myModel.save();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can pass any jQuery ajax options in the second param to save(). For example:

```
myModel.save({}, { url: "/index?id=001&email=user@email.com" });
```

If you need to generalize this or DRY it up, then rewriting sync is probably a better idea.

Comment: im actually trying to do a post on the form not just pass the params

Comment: You do know that if those attributes exist on the model, they are just posted by default, right? Your question implied that you needed a non-standard URL.